# Show that $\alpha t-\log(t)$ has compact level set.

Tags: analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}_{++}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x>0\}$.

I need to show that for $t\in \mathbb{R}_{++}$: $t\mapsto \alpha t -\log(t)$ has a compact level set for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, where $N(c)=\{t\in \mathbb{R}_{++}\mid\alpha t-\log(t)\leq c\}$ is the level set to the value $c$. 
For $t \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ it holds that $\alpha t - \log(t)=c=:\text{constant} \implies \frac{1}{e^{c}}=t\cdot e^{-\alpha t}$. By the substitution $u=\alpha t$ I get $u=W\left(\frac{\alpha}{e^{c}}\right)$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function. Since we havent even introduced this function, I think that this is the wrong way to get the solution to my problem. Apart from that, I don't know how to get the compact level set from here.

EDIT.
Maybe I could use the fact that $\alpha t- \log(t)$ is convex? The level sets of a convex function are convex. The levelset ist bounded by definition. I just need to proof that the level set is closured. Maybe that can help me out: On an open, konvex , notempty set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ defined function (like $\alpha t-log(t)$) is continous, if the function is convex. Thus i show with the continous function, that every limit point of a convergent serie in $N(c)$ lies in $N(c)$. Than i am done.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_{++}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}$. You are right. I fixed it, i missread. sry. My problem is in one dimension

Comment: t positive real. sry i'm alrdy confused by that much excercises.

Comment: fixed the original post

Comment: Ah, so the original problem was really one-dimensional? Or did you oversimplify by mistake?

Comment: yeah it was. and i think i only need to show, that the level set is closured.

Answer (score 0):

The level sets are *finite*, which implies immediately that they are compact. Since $\Bbb R_{++}$ is a $T_1$ space, they are also closed.